# Cannot complete knitting r markdown project to pdf or HTML

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I have my r markdown project and when I try to knit it to pdf or HTML it loads until I get to the bottom. I then get this error code. I have never used LaTeX before so I don't know if it is an issue in that, or possibly that I have not installed all the packages I need on my computer, or some other issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Becca, can you please provide a reproducible example of your markdown code?

Comment: If you don't have luck with MiKTeX, you may try TinyTeX instead: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

giving a shortcut to what Yihui said, run

```
install.packages("tinytex")
```

inside R